# Media refers to specific PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is that I would like URLs to my media:
http://example.org/upload/my-media.jpg
to refer to a specific PHP page, or at least be able to style the HTML in it.
I've attempted to achieve this with rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^upload/([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]*)$ http://example.org/image.php?file=$1 [L]
```

But that doesn't allow me to redirect while preserving the URL, I assume there must be a different way to go about achieving what I need, I've tried googling it but I can't find the correct terminology to use in order to get the right result.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is example.com an external website?

Comment: Yes, pointed domain by A Record to a public IP